# Python: Are a,b=1,2 and a=1;b=2 strictly equivalent?

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, syntax

I am puzzled with the following:

This works:

```
a, b = 1071, 1029
while(a%b != 0):
    a, b = b, a%b
```

But, the following snippet returns a **ZeroDivisionError** error message:

```
a, b = 1071, 1029
while(a%b != 0):
    a = b; b = a%b
```

while I expected both would be strictly equivalent.

Can anyone throw the light on this, please?

Comment: Why are you asking one question in the headline and an entirely different one in the text?

Comment: it is the same question

Comment: They aren't the same question, but that's only apparent when you understand how `a,b = 1, 2` works, which would preclude asking the question :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. In

```
a, b = b, a%b
```

the right-hand side is evaluated into a tuple first, so `a%b` is calculated using the original value of `a`. In contrast,

```
a = b; b = a%b
```

`a%b` is calculated *after* `a` as been assigned the value of `b`, assigning a different result to `b`.